# WooCommerce product WPML translation inserted by REST API doesn't include variations of original product

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, wpml

Unfortunately I'm working with wordpress and woocommerce, what I'm trying to accomplish is to insert products and relative translations using the [woocommerce REST API](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs), here's the scenario:

- First, i [create](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product) a simple product

```
{
 "name": "Dummy",
 "type": "variable",
 "attributes": [
     {
         "id": 2,
         "name": "Color",
         "position": 1,
         "variation": "true",
         "options": [
             "Bianco",
             "Nero"
         ]
     },
     {
         "id": 3,
         "name": "Size",
         "position": 2,
         "variation": "true",
         "options": [
             "A",
             "B",
             "C"
         ]
     }
 ]
}
```

This is a variable product, so I need to create its variations as well
The product created return its id, let's say 10

- Then I [create several product variations](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product-variation) like this:

```
{
    "regular_price": "10.10",
    "stock_quantity": 10,
    "attributes": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Color",
            "option": "Bianco"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Size",
            "option": "A"
        }
    ]
}
```

- So I have a product with variations, now i want to create a translation of the product with wpml, according to [wmpl rest api specifications](https://wpml.org/documentation/related-projects/woocommerce-multilingual/using-wordpress-rest-api-woocommerce-multilingual/), I create a product translation like this:

```
{
    "name": "Dummy en",
    "type": "variable",
    "lang": "en",
    "translation_of": 10
}
```

- I specified the language `en`, the main language is `it`
- I included `translation_of` with the id of the original product

What happens is that the english product is created, but without variations

What I have tried:

- Several issues similar to this are solved by the troubleshooting page of wpml, where I can generate missing variations but I need this to be done automatically, products are created automatically, so relative translations too must be
- If I enter product page from wordpress back end and I press the update button, variations are created and adjusted, this word for the original product and the variation, but again, I need this to be done automatically
- I tried to modify and insert the translation in almost all ways, adding/removing sku, id, attributes, categories ecc.

Any hints? Thanks

Comment: any luck with that? I am trying same thing...

Comment: Hi, this was nearly a year ago, in the meantime we just threw away this woocommerce crap and rewritten everything from scratch, I hope you will find a solution or do the same